# How to show only one class with same name

Tags: html, css

in my code

```
<ol class="items">            
    <li class="item">
       <span class="filter-label">Category</span>
       <span class="filter-value">Fashion</span>                                                                                                                                                    
       <a class="action remove" href="https://www.marketplacedemo.store/online-store?cat=226" title="Remove Category Fashion">
           <span>Remove This Item</span>
       </a>                                                                    
    </li>            
    <li class="item">
        <span class="filter-label">Category</span>
        <span class="filter-value">Deal of day-Home</span>                                                                                                                               
        <a class="action remove" href="https://www.marketplacedemo.store/online-store?cat=109" title="Remove Category Deal of day-Home">
           <span>Remove This Item</span>
         </a>                                               
    </li>
</ol>
```

now in this I want to show only one **Category** else all of the category need to be *display:none* now for that I've tried

```
.filter-label{
    display:none;
}
.items:nth-of-type(1) >.filter-label:first-child {
  display:block;
}
```

but it is not working.

how can I show only one category? any help will be really appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `:not` selector

```css
.items li:not(:first-child) .filter-label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ol class="items">            
    <li class="item">
        <span class="filter-label">Category</span>
        <span class="filter-value">Fashion</span>                                        
        <a class="action remove" href="https://www.marketplacedemo.store/online-store?cat=226" title="Remove Category Fashion">
          <span>Remove This Item</span>
        </a>                                                                    
    </li>            
    <li class="item">
        <span class="filter-label">Category</span>
        <span class="filter-value">Deal of day-Home</span>                   
        <a class="action remove" href="https://www.marketplacedemo.store/online-store?cat=109" title="Remove Category Deal of day-Home">
           <span>Remove This Item</span>
        </a>                                               
    </li>
</ol>
```